# HTML5 Video not playing in ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, iis

I'm not really sure why the HTML5 video in my asp.net page will not play.  I checked the network tab on Chrome dev tools and it gets the file correctly.  However on the page it only shows the HTML5 player with black screen, No video is showing. And I have also put the mp4 mimetypes in the `Web.config`.

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
<mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
</staticContent>
```

```
<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
    <source src="../Videos/exterior/SampleVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

If I put the same source code in a plain html the video will show correctly.  So I'm not really sure if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Had it resolve actually. I was testing it only in Chrome but works in other browsers.  To get it to work in Chrome I need the video in a `.webm` format and it works.